# three.js JSONLoader Unexpected token

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to import a 3D model encoded as json file using the respectively "JSONLoader" three.js function

Here's the code to load the model

```
var t_rex;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load('t-rex.json', addModelToScene)

function addModelToScene(geometry,materials){
  var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
  t_rex = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)
  t_rex.scale.set(0.2,0.2,0.2)
  scene.add(t_rex)
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

What am I missing?

I think it may be useful to include the complete code as well

Edit:

As suggested here's the first lines of the JSON:

```
"metadata":{
    "materials":1,
    "faces":84060,
    "vertices":133095,
    "normals":132794,
    "uvs":1,
    "type":"Geometry",
    "generator":"io_three",
    "version":3
},
"materials":[{
    "transparent":true,
    "colorSpecular":[0,0,0],
    "wireframe":false,
    "doubleSided":false,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.588,0.588,0.588],
    "DbgIndex":0,
    "depthWrite":true,
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "shading":"phong",
    "opacity":1,
    "visible":true,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "blending":1,
    "DbgName":"Rex_M_INST",
    "specularCoef":6,
    "depthTest":true
}],
"uvs":[[0.0395487,0.309911 ......lots of others number
```

Comment: You should include the first few lines of the JSON file, if at all possible, as part of providing a complete example. Without seeing the file, most answers and comments are likely to simply state that your JSON file starts with a `<` and that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Also check the network tab and the relative URL of the file... the `<` character is often a sign you're getting a 404 page from the server.

Comment: @tehhowch I've checked the JSON file, it doesn't start with < and it's a valid JSON file.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy the network tab is reporting only this error, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, which seemed to arrive when I upgraded to Three.js 0.92, although looking at the source code it doesn't look like anything changed recently in jsonLoader.

After some investigation the issue fixed itself once I removed some whitespace from the end of my json file (which was generated with the Blender plugin).